# c++ graph input problem, finding the ways of an input?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

we had a algorithm coding event in our school today, and they asked a question and no one could answer. I am trying to find an answer by using only standard library. (I am trying to solve this without .h files because in contests they want us to solve it like that.) So basically question is as follows:

*Write a (C / C++) program that will get a graph model as an argument.

*You must get this values from console while we are starting your application.

*Your program must write down all the possible word combination by using the graph model.

Ex Input on Console to call your app: “yourapp.exe 5ABCD1BCD1CDE”
After your application name, second word gives you information about the graph.

- Notation: [STEPS][FROM1-TO1-TO2-...TOn]1[FROM2-TO1-TO2-...TOn]1 .....
- [STEPS] First integer value ( 5 in our example) is the maximum word length to measure.
- [FROM TO ... TO] blocks show connections in the graph. Each node is symbolized with one Upper
  Letter. First on is connections start position others are destinations. Each connection(link) is one
  way. So: “ABCD” means we have connection from A to B , A to C and A to D
- The first node in the text is the start point for word creation.

This input means you have a graph like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0wjc.jpg

Desired Output:
A
AB
AC
AD
ABD
ABC
ABCD
ABCE
ACD
ACE

--------------------------------------------END OF THE QUESTION-----------------------------------------------------

I personally tried to find the index numbers in input, connection starts and etc. but i couldn't figured out how to solve this properly. Please help :=)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int inputLength,maxLength,digitLength;
string word,digitIndex,starters;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Saving the graph input as a variable named word

    word = argv[1];

    //Finding the max word and input lengths
    maxLength=word[0] -'0';
    inputLength=word.length();

    cout<<"Your graph input "<<word<<endl;
    cout<<"Maximum word length : "<<maxLength<<endl;

    //Finding the digitIndexes in input.
    for(int i=0;i<inputLength;i++){
        if(isdigit(word[i])){
            digitIndex+=to_string(i);
        }
    }
    digitLength=digitIndex.length();

    cout<<"digit indexes : "<<digitIndex<<endl;
    cout<<"digitindex[1] : "<<digitIndex[1]-'0'<<endl;
    cout<<"your word : "<<word<<endl;

    //Finding the connection starts
    for(int i=0; i<inputLength;i++){
        if(isdigit(word[i])==true){
            starters+=word[i+1];
        }
    }
    cout<<"starters : "<<starters<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Unrelated tactical note: it is a bad idea to use `argv` without first confirming with `argc` that the argument you want actually exists.

Comment: @hopelessdevxd: I provided a solution below. But I am wondering, why in your shown or required output, the sequence of "ABD ABC" is reveresed? Maybe that is a typo?

Comment: Please do not use - using namespace std;

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. But easy to implement using `std::algorithms` and recursive calls. Also, the data structure selection may help to design such an application.

Unfortunately, the description of the input format is not fully clear. I understand the “steps” part, but there is no description for the rest of the digits. I assume that they are simply delimiters and have no further meaning.

We will split the big task into some subtasks. And, we will use a class Graph, where we store all needed data and functions.

So, obviously the first task is, to split the input string. For that we extract the first characters consisting of digits and convert them to the integer value “steps”. The rest of the string will be tokenized by using a C++ standard functionality: The `std::sregex_token_iterator`.

This thing is an iterator. For iterating over a string, hence “sregex”. The `begin()`/`end()` part defines, on what range of input we shall operate, then there is a `std::regex` for what should be matched / or what should not be matched in the input string. The type of matching strategy is given with last parameter.

- 1 --> give me the stuff that I defined in the regex and
- -1 --> give me that what is NOT matched based on the regex

We can use this iterator for storing the tokens in a `std::vector`. The `std::vector` has a range constructor, which takes 2 iterators as parameter, and copies the data between the first iterator and 2nd iterator to the `std::vector`. The statement:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::sregex_token_iterator(init.begin(), init.end(), re, 1), {});
```

defines a variable “split” as a `std::vector` and uses the so called range-constructor of the std::vector.

You can see that I do not use the `std::sregex_token_iterator`’s "end()"-iterator for the `std::vector` explicitly.This iterator will be constructed from the empty brace-enclosed initializer list with the correct type, because it will be deduced to be the same as the type of the first argument due to the `std::vector` constructor requiring that.

Then we transform the resulting “from-to”-strings to our target storage. This is a `std::map` consisting of the “from” character as a key, and a `std::vector` of char’s (the targets) as the value. With that we always have an association from one start point (Vertex) to all end points and with that, implicitly the “Edges”. This data structure will span a virtual tree, which we can later traverse to find the required result.

We put all this in an “init” function, can call it from the class constructor and also from the overwritten extractor operator. I added the extractor as an additional functionality to make life easier. So you do not need to use the `main`-functions `argc` and `argv`, but can directly read from `std::cin` via:

```
Graph graph;
std::cin >> graph;
```

Now we have all data in our map and can start to build the solution. We will store all resulting “ways” in a `std::vector` of `std::string`. For building the “ways” we “track” the way through the “graph”. So, every time, when we see a new vertex, we add it to the “track” and if we reach the end of a route or if the route is longer than “steps”, we store the new track in “ways”.

So, the OP requested a special output format. To create this, we must use “Breadth First”- or “Level Order”-Traversal. Meaning, before we descent (with a simple recursive algorithm) we need to go horizontally, resulting in 2 for loops. But no problem. Very simple.

For a simple output functionality, I have overwritten the inserter operator.

And, I do validate the input (I allow also lower letters).

Please see the full working example below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <regex>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

//std::string test{"5ABCD1BCD1CDE"};
std::regex re1(R"(([a-zA-Z]+))");
std::regex re2(R"(([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)+)");

using Map = std::map<char, std::vector<char>>;

class Graph {
public:
    // Constructor
    Graph() : steps(), fromTo(), root(), ways(), track() {}
    Graph(const std::string input) : steps(), fromTo(), root(), ways(), track() { init(input); }

    // Build the result
    void build() { int level{ 0 }; rBuild(root, level); }

    // inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Graph& g) {
        std::copy(g.ways.begin(), g.ways.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, " "));
        return os << "\n";
    }

    // extractor
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Graph& g) {
        if (std::string input{}; std::getline(is, input)) g.init(input);
        return is;
    }
private:
    // Values derived from input
    int steps{};
    Map fromTo{};
    char root{};

    // The result
    std::vector<std::string> ways{};
    std::string track{};
    // Recursive function to build all ways
    void rBuild(const char vertex, int& level);
    // Initialize source values
    void init(const std::string& input);
};

void Graph::init(const std::string& input) {

    fromTo.clear(), ways.clear(); track.clear(); steps = 0; root = '\0';
    if (std::regex_match(input, re2)) {
        // Get steps
        size_t pos{}; steps = std::stoi(input, &pos); std::string init = input.substr(pos);

        // Split string into substrings
        std::vector<std::string> split(std::sregex_token_iterator(init.begin(), init.end(), re1, 1), {});

        // Get root
        root = split[0][0]; track += root; ways.push_back(track);

        // Convert substrings to map entries
        std::transform(split.begin(), split.end(), std::inserter(fromTo, fromTo.end()), [](std::string & s) {
            return std::make_pair(s[0], std::vector<char>(std::next(s.begin()), s.end())); });
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "\n***** Error:  Wrong input format\n";
}

// Recursive function to build all ways through the graph
void Graph::rBuild(const char vertex, int& level) {

    // Allow only a certain depth, while descencing down
    if (level < steps-1) {

        // Search the start point for this entry
        if (Map::iterator node{ fromTo.find(vertex) }; node != fromTo.end()) {

            // Go through all edges to just the next vertex. This is not a breadth first traversal 
            // So, first we will go horizontally
            for (const char to : node->second) {
                // We want to track the way that we were going so far
                track.push_back(to);
                // Saving this track as a new way
                ways.push_back(track);
                // Restoring the origninal track befor this way, so that we can generate the next way
                track.pop_back();
            }
            // and now we will descent
            for (const char to : node->second) {
                // One level further down
                ++level;
                // track will be one vertex longer
                track.push_back(to);
                // Recursive call, descent
                rBuild(to, level);
                // And backwards 
                track.pop_back();
                --level;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        std::string test = argv[1];

        // Define and initialize the graph
        Graph graph(test);
        // Build the required strings
        graph.build();
        // Show result
        std::cout << graph;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "\nEnter init string: \n";
        if (Graph graph; std::cin >> graph) {
            // Build the required strings
            graph.build();
            // Show result
            std::cout << "\nResult:\n" << graph << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What a pity that nobody will read that . . .